# Why do query results differ if a dataset is materialized?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a set of data which can relate to itself:

```
public class SomeDataObject {

public int ID { get; set; }

public int? ParentID { get; set; }

public virtual SomeDataObject Parent {get; set; }

public bool Deleted { get; set; }

}
```

DataExample:

| ID | ParentID | Deleted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |

The following snippet returns a list with one element:

```
var result = Context.Current.SomeDataObjects.Where(sdo => !sdo.Deleted).ToList();
result = result.Where(r => r.ParentID == null).ToList();
```

The following returns an empty collection:

```
var result = Context.Current.SomeDataObjects.Where(sdo => !sdo.Deleted && sdo.ParentID == null ).ToList();
```

Why do the results differ - the query is the same - what do I miss?

Edit:

```
public IDbSet<SomeDataObject> SomeDataObjects { get; set; }

modelBuilder.Entity<SomeDataObject>().HasRequired(sdo => sdo.Parent).WithMany().HasForeignKey(sdo => sdo.ParentId);
```

I'm working with existing code, so I am trying to break it down for myself. My guess here is, that the error occurs because of the .HasRequired() which should be .HasOptional() - otherwise the nullable ParentId wouldn`t make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, the example was incomplete - i added the .ToList();

Comment: [I can't reproduce](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sftBkV)

Comment: @Cid LINQ-to-Objects (what you show) and LINQ-to-Entities/LINQ-to-SQL that OP used are quite different beasts... Which is exactly what OP is asking about.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov oh, okay, I never used the To Entities/SQL ones

Comment: Try printing the actual SQL query to see if there is substantial difference.

Comment: I don't think this sample actually reproduces the problem you're seeing. The only difference is that the former query will let both entities pass the change tracker, as they both conform to the Where() that gets compiled to SQL (`WHERE DELETED = 0`) and do the second filter in memory (Linq to Objects), while the second will translate to `WHERE DELETED = 0 AND ParentID IS NULL` (Linq to Entities) and perform the entire filter in SQL. Make sure that your sample is a [mre].

Comment: Thanks @CodeCaster - i`ve added further informations and I'm trying to provide an minimal reproducible example out of my existing application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My guess here is, that the error occurs because of the .HasRequired() which should be .HasOptional() - otherwise the nullable ParentId wouldn`t make sense.

That's exactly it. Because you instruct the model builder that the `SomeDataObject Parent` is required, Entity Framework will see your `Where(sdo => ... sdo.ParentID == null)` query and generate a `WHERE 1 = 0`, because you feed it a query that, according to your configuration, will never yield any records anyway.

If the relationship is optional, mark it as such.